# Using model in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to hide a button based on a value in my model which I am passing to the page.

```
    @model Indigo.Contracts.DataContracts.JobDetailDto

    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if(@Model.StatusNameInternal === "Completed")
            {
                $('#cancelButton').prop("hidden", true);
            }
            });
    </script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="restartButton" value="Restart" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="finalizeButton" value="Finalize" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to do is, when my document is ready, check if the StatusNameInternal = "Completed", then hide the cancelButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. Since `@Model.StatusNameInternal` resolves to a string, you need to quote that value in your JavaScript:

```
if ('@Model.StatusNameInternal' === 'Completed') {
```

Also, I'm not sure that `.prop('hidden', true)` will do what you want. I think you probably want `.hide()` or `.css('visibility', 'hidden')`.

Comment: You were correct, it seems that I was close. And the 'hidden' doesn't work, so I'm using the .hide() now.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if(@Model.StatusNameInternal === "Completed")
                {
                    $('#cancelButton').hide();
                }
                });
        </script>
```